Расстановка кораблей на поле (Консольный морской бой) на C#
Хочу написать консольный морской бой, сейчас у меня только выводится поле игрока.
using System;


class Program
{
    static int fieldSize = 10;
    static char[,] PlayerField = new char[fieldSize, fieldSize];
    static char[,] OpponentField = new char[fieldSize, fieldSize];
    static Random rnd = new Random();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        InitializateField(PlayerField);
        InitializateField(OpponentField);

        PrintField(PlayerField, "Поле игрока:");
            

    }

    static void InitializateField(char [,] field)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < fieldSize; ++i)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < fieldSize; ++j)
            {
                field[i,j] = '~';
            }
        }
    }


    static void PrintField(char[,] field, string nameOfField)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(nameOfField);
        Console.Write("  ");
        for (int i = 0; i < fieldSize; ++i)
            Console.Write($"{i + 1} ");
        Console.WriteLine();  

        for (int i = 0; i < fieldSize; ++i)
        {
            Console.Write($"{(char)('A' + i)} ");
            for (int j = 0; j < fieldSize; ++j)
            {
                Console.Write($"{field[i,j]} ");
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }  
    }

}

Вот прям вообще не понимаю как можно расставить корабли на поле, всё что могу это самому расставить 10 раз рандомно корабли, а потом вызвать рандом в диапазоне (0, 9) и для каждого значения будет в case своя ручная расстановка. Так вот как бы мне понять алгоритм расстановки кораблей на поле?
ВОТ ТУТ МЕТОДЫ ДЛЯ РАССТАНОВКИ КОРАБЛЕЙ:
 static void PlaceShips(char[,] field)
        {
            PlaceShip(field, 4); 
            for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) PlaceShip(field, 3); 
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) PlaceShip(field, 2); 
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) PlaceShip(field, 1); 
        }

    
        static void PlaceShip(char[,] field, int size)
        {
            bool placed = false;
            while (!placed)
            {
                // Выбираем случайное направление: 0 - горизонтально, 1 - вертикально
                int direction = rnd.Next(2);
                // Случайные координаты для начальной точки корабля
                int row = rnd.Next(fieldSize);
                int col = rnd.Next(fieldSize);

                if (CanPlaceShip(field, row, col, size, direction))
                {
                    // Размещаем корабль
                    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
                    {
                        if (direction == 0)
                            field[row, col + i] = 'S'; // горизонтально
                        else
                            field[row + i, col] = 'S'; // вертикально
                    }
                    placed = true;
                }
            }
        }

    // Проверка, можно ли разместить корабль
        static bool CanPlaceShip(char[,] field, int row, int col, int size, int direction)
        {
            // Проверяем, не выходит ли корабль за границы
            if (direction == 0 && col + size > fieldSize) return false; // горизонтально
            if (direction == 1 && row + size > fieldSize) return false; // вертикально

            // Проверяем, что на пути корабля нет других кораблей
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            {
                int r = row + (direction == 1 ? i : 0);
                int c = col + (direction == 0 ? i : 0);

                if (field[r, c] == 'S' || !IsSurroundingAreaClear(field, r, c))
                {
                    return false; // Есть пересечения
                }
            }

            return true;
        }

    // Проверка, что вокруг клетки корабля нет других кораблей
        static bool IsSurroundingAreaClear(char[,] field, int row, int col)
        {
            for (int i = row - 1; i <= row + 1; i++)
            {
                for (int j = col - 1; j <= col + 1; j++)
                {
                    if (i >= 0 && i < fieldSize && j >= 0 && j < fieldSize)
                    {
                        if (field[i, j] == 'S')
                            return false;
                    }
                }
            }
            return true;
        }

Но я вот думаю что это будет очень сложно разобрать, как мне разобрать эти методы чтобы я понял как она генерируют корабли?

Оставлю пожалуй это тут.

@EvgeniyZ это конечено крутой, но как это можно понять?

А что там понимать? Вот что вам не понятно? Там ведь самые базовые, простейшие механики C#, простые циклы, методы, да и все по сути. Если вы тут ничего не понимаете, то советую начать с более простого, калькулятор допустим. Ну а если не понятна конкретная вещь, то конкретизируйте вопрос.

Интересно, а как вы будете реализовывать ручное добавление кораблей? По типу "Напишите размер, начальную и конечную позицию корабля"?) Уж не проще ли это будет сделать графически? Хотя отмечу, то консольная реализация это... необычно

Посмотрел ваш код, посмотрел код @EvgeniyZ и написал что-то среднее.
Первое, что бросилось в глаза, это проверка возможности установить корабль. Зачем проверять 9 клеток по координатам, если проверки соседних клеток будут пересекаться? Не проще ли проверить сразу весь прямоугольник за один присест?
Например такой для 4-палубного?
~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~
~ S S S S ~
~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~

То есть 3 на 6. Логично же?
Ну вот и метод родился:
static bool CanPlaceShip(char[,] grid, int row, int col, int height, int width)
{
    for (int i = row; i < row + height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = col; j < col + width; j++)
        {
            if (i >= 0 && i < grid.GetLength(0) && j >= 0 && j < grid.GetLength(1) && grid[i, j] == 'S')
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}

Теперь генератор кораблей
У нас по сути последовательность генерации по размерам кораблей есть [4, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1]. Такая последовательность генерируется двумя вложенными циклами алгоритмически. Где внешний это перечисление размеров от 4 до 1, а внутренний их количество, которое вычисляется по формуле 4 - размер + 1.
Далее как было у @EvgeniyZ, пытаемся воткнуть корабль на случайные координаты со случайным направлением до тех пор, пока не воткнётся.
Родился ещё один метод:
static void PlaceShips(char[,] grid)
{
    Random rnd = Random.Shared;
    for (int shipSize = 4; shipSize > 0; shipSize--)
    {
        for (int count = 0; count <= 4 - shipSize; count++)
        {
            while (true)
            {
                int vertical = rnd.Next(2);
                int horizontal = 1 - vertical;
                int rowOffset = (shipSize - 1) * vertical;
                int colOffset = (shipSize - 1) * horizontal;
                int row = rnd.Next(grid.GetLength(0) - rowOffset);
                int col = rnd.Next(grid.GetLength(1) - colOffset);

                if (CanPlaceShip(grid, row - 1, col - 1, 3 + rowOffset, 3 + colOffset))
                {
                    for (int s = 0; s < shipSize; s++)
                    {
                        grid[row + s * vertical, col + s * horizontal] = 'S';
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

Здесь почти нет условий, одно всего. Всё остальное банальная математика.

vertical случайное число 0 или 1, оно 1 если корабль вертикальный.
horizontal - 1 если горизонтальный.

С помощью такого подхода к определению направления корабля легко вычислять координаты его границ и расположения клеток математически.
Ну и пару служебных методов создания матрицы и её печати:
static char[,] CreateGrid(int size)
{
    char[,] grid = new char[size, size];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
        {
            grid[i, j] = '~';
        }
    }
    return grid;
}

static void Print(char[,] grid)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < grid.GetLength(0); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < grid.GetLength(1); j++)
        {
            Console.Write($"{grid[i, j]} ");
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}

Поехали:
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    char[,] grid = CreateGrid(10);
    PlaceShips(grid);
    Print(grid);
}

Вывод в консоль:
~ ~ S S S ~ ~ S ~ ~
~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~
S ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ S S ~ ~
~ ~ ~ ~ S ~ ~ ~ ~ ~
S ~ ~ ~ S ~ S ~ ~ ~
~ ~ ~ ~ S ~ S ~ ~ S
~ S ~ ~ S ~ ~ ~ ~ ~
~ S ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~
~ S ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ S ~ ~
~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ S ~ ~


Человек походу не понимает базовые принципы языка, не понимает что в коде за что отвечает, и что делает. Так что, здесь не решение нужно, а скорей всего надо опуститься на самый базовый уровень и тыкая пальцем сказать что и за что отвечает.

@EvgeniyZ я старался именно алгоритм объяснить, плюс алгоритмически упростить код на максимум. Ни одного тернарника не осталось. Ну посмотрим, как зайдёт.

а PlaceShips гарантирует что всегда можно расположить корабли? Или в каких-то случаях это все может уйти в бесконечный цикл?

@Grundy указанный массив из 10 кораблей можно гарантированно расположить на сетке 10х10 при условии, если начать с самого большого. Возможно ли в обратном порядке - не проверял.

@aepot Простите что я не понимаю, но можете пояснить за это:
                int colOffset = (shipSize - 1) * horizontal;
                int row = rnd.Next(grid.GetLength(0) - rowOffset);
                int col = rnd.Next(grid.GetLength(1) - colOffset);```

@AslanPAPA что именно непонятно, знак вычитания, умножения, или присваивания? Что получится, если любое число умножить на один? А на ноль?

@aepot ну вот shipSize = 4 далее в зависимости от рандомного vertical мы получим корабль либо по вертикали либо по горизонтали, хорошо, но дальше int rowOffset = (shipSize - 1) * vertical;
Зачем мы отнимает от shipSize (4) - 1 и умножаем его к примеру на 1 т.е вертикально.

@AslanPAPA получаем число, насколько корабль длиннее в этом направлении, чем одноклеточный.

@aepot а как с помощью этого мы "получаем число, насколько корабль длиннее в этом направлении, чем одноклеточный"

@AslanPAPA ну возмите бумажку и ручку, видите формулу, подставьте числа. Считать до 4 в первом классе школы уже все умеют. У одноклеточного какой размер? 1, верно? Если размер shipSize равен 4, а направление vertical равно 1, то по формуле rowOffset вычислится как 3 (4 - 1) * 1 = 3. То же самое с colOffset. Далее начальная точка корабля имеет смысл если корабль влезает в сетку. Горизонтальный 4 клетки, то col будет от 0 до 6 col = rnd(10 - 3) * 1 = rnd(7) = от 0 до 6. Если размер корабля 3, то от 0 до 7, если 1, то от 0 до 9 координата будет. То же самое со второй координатой.

@AslanPAPA смысла нет генерировать начальную координату колонки 9 для 4-клеточного горизонтального корабля, верно? Заведомо же известно, что не влезет, логично? Поэтому от размера поля по горизонтали отнимаем 3 для 4-клетночного корабля. Индексы в массиве из 10 элементов это от 0 до 9. Рандом с аргументом 10 даст число от 0 до 9, а с аргументом 7 даст число от 0 до 6. Так и получится, что 4-клеточный корабль займёт колонки с индексами 6,7,8 и 9. Если начали с 6, то есть с самой правой подходящей клетки. С клетки 7 начинать смысла нет, потому что 7,8,9,10 получится, а колонки 10 не существует.

@aepot Все что я могу это еще раз извенится и ещё раз спрашивать на счет того как работает метод CanPlaceShip зачем мы в него передаем row - 1, col - 1, 3 + rowOffset, 3 + colOffset так же не понятно здесь grid[row + s * vertical, col + s * horizontal] = 'S';

@AslanPAPA отредактировал вопрос, поменял схему области, которую занимает 4-палубный корабль. Вверху вопроса. Так вот если row, col это координата левой клетки корабля, то левыйф верхний угол где? Правильно row -1, col - 1. Возмите калькулятор, подставьте числа и посчитайте, сколько чего будет. Либо поставьте точку останова и выполняйте код пошагово, учитесь отлаживать код https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/visualstudio/get-started/csharp/tutorial-debugger
